# ngx-bootstrap datepicker localization month is lowercase

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

When I localize `BsDatepicker` monthes are lowercase except English localization

```
import { kkLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
import { ruLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
defineLocale('kk', kkLocale);
defineLocale('ru', ruLocale);
```

How can I make all Titlecase or Lowercase?

[image: rus locale][image: eng locale]
[image][image]

Comment: if I am right , you can provide your own language JSON file. let me check

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/chronos/i18n/en-gb.ts and https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty ez , I have just changed some css

```
.bs-datepicker-head .current span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.bs-datepicker-body table tbody tr td span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its working through css only Please try this in style.css file

```css
div.bs-datepicker-body>table.months>tbody>tr>td>span {
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
}
```